# Chrome Debugger Doesn't Pause Mid-Scroll ... Fixable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

When I put a `debugger` statement inside some code that is called `onScroll`, the Chrome development tools do something strange that I haven't seen before: instead of pausing the browser with a gray overlay AND pausing the dev tools debugger on the appropriate line, Chrome only does the latter.  In other words, it pauses in the debugging pane, but the browser remains active, allowing me to continue scroll (or do anything else) in the browser.

Is there anything I can do to make the browser truly halt both the debugger AND the browser pane?